# how to define that a nonlinear operator is bounded and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

We always see the definition of bounded and continuous linear operator.
I am wondering how to define that a nonlinear operator is bounded and continuous.
Is there any book providing this definition?

Comment: A bounded linear operator is the same as a continuous linear operator. There is the obvious way to define continuous linear operators, if that's the generalization you're looking for.

Comment: Boundedness is the same definition; that is, we say that a nonlineat operator between Banach spaces $T:X\rightarrow Y$ Is bounded if there is $ C > 0 $ such that $ \| T x \| _Y \le C \| x\| _X $. The continuity, in general, does **not** follow from boundedness. (Continuity is defined as topological continuity)

Answer (score 4):

Like in my comment above, we have big distinctions between linear and nonlinear operators:

- For a *linear* operator $ T : X \rightarrow Y $ it is a basic result that continuity and boundedness are in fact equivalent.
- For a *nonlinear* operator, things change a bit, and we cannot obtain continuity from boundedness directly. Thus, we define boundedness as

$$ \exists C > 0; \|Tx\| _Y \le C\|x\|_X \;\forall x \in X $$

And continuity as topological continuity: if $ x_n \rightarrow x $, then $ Tx_n \rightarrow Tx $.

Some examples of nonlinear operators for which the two conditions hold are general maximal operators, like the Hardy-Littlewood maximal Operator, which is continuous and bounded on $ L^p $ and on $ W^{k,p} $ ($1<p$)

Comment: Could you suggest some good books containing an introduction to nonlinear analysis?